# RegEx matches two results single line as one

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have JavaScript a code

```
var docBodyText = document.body.innerHTML;
var patt =/<!--:.+:-->/g;
patt.compile(patt);
var matchesB=docBodyText.match(patt)
```

and a HTML page

```
<body>
<span><b><!--:?time:--> <!--:?date:--></b></span>
<br />
<!--:?url:-->
</body>
```

When I execute the script it returns
`["<!--:?time:--><!--:?date:-->","<!--:?url:-->"]`

but I want
`<!--:?time:-->` and `<!--:?date:-->`
 to be returned separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). The `+` by default means "1 or more times, but prefer as many as possible". Add a `?` modifier after the `+` to make it match lazily:

```
var patt =/<!--:.+?:-->/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the pattern to exclude other `>` tags:

```
var patt =/<!--:[^>]+:-->/g;
```

Comment: I think you mean square brackets, not parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript regex are greedy by default. You need to use the non-greedy qualifier for this to get the shortes matching string.

```
var patt =/<!--:.+?:-->/g;
```